# I'm getting an "Unexpected unindent error"

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

I'm creating a program and I recently started exception handling. The program worked fine a couple times but now I'm getting an `IndentationError` every time it starts, which is bizarre because it worked fine before. It is large, so I'm only including a snippet of the program. Let me know if you need the whole thing.

The only way I can get it to work is if I delete the command

I've included some lines in-between the commands so you can more clearly identify them. The problem command is the one in the middle.

```
elif 'python' in cmd:
    pythonProgram = cmd.split(' ')[1]
    execfile(pythonProgram)

elif 'cd' in cmd:
    desired_directory = cmd.split(' ')[1]
    if desired_directory == "..":
        os.chdir('..')
    else:
        try:
            os.chdir(desired_directory)
            print "'%s' Is not a valid directory!" % desired_directory

elif 'ver' in cmd:
    print"JDOS_2", currentVersion
```

I've also attempted to hash out the lower `elif` and gotten the same error with the next `elif` statement in the program.

This seems like a simple problem, and I'm most likely overseeing something, but the indentations of elif commands are the same. This is the error output.

```
  File "/Users/#######/PycharmProjects/untitled/JDOS/SYS64/jdosos.py", line 64
    elif cmd == "ver":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And I haven't had any problems mixing spaces and indents as its littered all over my program.

Comment: Your `try` doesn't have a matching `except` block

Comment: You don't have an `except` or a `finally` case for your `try`

Comment: Are you missing the `except` block or did you not include it?

Comment: Not entirely sure how that would be implemented into it, but thanks!

Comment: Any guide on exception handling would demonstrate it; it' a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I needed a matching `except` block to go with the `try` argument.

This is the fixed code and works perfectly.

```
elif 'cd' in cmd:
    desired_directory = cmd.split('cd ')[1]
    if desired_directory == "..":
        os.chdir('..')
    else:
        try:
            os.chdir(desired_directory)
        except OSError as e:
            print("'%s' Is not a valid directory!" % desired_directory)
```